# Qt: QGraphicObject and QImage

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qimage

I have a `QGraphicsObject` derived class that holds a `QImage` and ovveride

```
paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
```

In the pain I succefully draw the `QImage`.
The `QGraphicsObject` is an item of `QGraphicsScene`, and the latter is inside a `QGraphicsView`. The `QImage` dimensions exceed the `QGraphicsScene` dimensions. My purpose is to `drag` the `QImage` (or the `QGraphicsObject`) in order to show the exceeding part of the `QImage`. How can I achive this? Have to `translate` the `QImage` canvas?

Could point me some kind of docs or example?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to just use a QGraphicsPixmapItem and let QGraphicsView handle the dragging for you:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#dragMode-prop

Comment: Actually I let the QGraphicsView manage the touch events and I applyed a QTransform to the QGraphicObject. What is you think about?